# ROS Time vs Wall time

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After a long simulation, I have realized with RViz that these two times do not match. While the ROS Elapsed time is 1700 seconds, the Wall Elapsed time is around 3630.  I would understand it if my simulation was slow or something, but RViz is running at 30FPS, I am not using Gazebo GUI, and the only 3 out of 8 CPUSs (real CPUs) are at 100%, while the others are between 30%-60%. And only 3.7/7.7 GB RAM are used.

Where does that time difference comes from then?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211092/ros-time-vs-wall-time/) by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1305 on 2015-06-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simple answer is: Because the simulation is running slower than realtime.

RViz, etc. does have nothing to do with that besides hogging CPU load.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-06-11**:
Thank you for your reply. Is there any way of speeding up simulation in gazebo_ros?

**Comment by [pulver](https://answers.ros.org/users/22461/pulver/) on 2021-01-29**:
Hi @Javier V. Gómez , I don't know if you are still interested but you can speed up gazebo simulations acting on the Real Time factor from the GUI or changing values in the .world file.

You can find a good description about how it works [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=physics_params&cat=physics).